# After select data from two table using JOIN I get NULL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to combine data from one table, and data from another table to get the list of employee.

The situation is following. In one table(t1 ->KPOL) I have columns like

```
SIFRA_RAD, DAT_IZD, POLICA, MAT_BROJ, MJE_SIG, UL_BROJ, OPSTINA, DAT_IZD
```

And another table(t2->SIFRAD) I have columns

```
SIFRA_R, IME, OSTALI_POD, DATUM_UNOSA, DATUM_PROMJENE, RADNIk_UNIO, DATUM_ISTEKA
```

Here is tabular schema of my data.

**KPOL**

```
  -------------------------------------------------Table KPOL------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SIFRA_RAD    DAT_IZD    POLICA      MAT_BROJ              MJE_SIG       UL_BROJ             OPSTINA              DAT_IZD

1.  "7654"      "1.1.2009"  "Z1A2B"      "06051987215444"       "USA"        "Neka Tamo 21"     "Jerricho"           "1.1.2015"
2   "4581"      "1.2.2007"  "A58547"     "65412398766666"       "DEU"        "Love Sthrase"     "Munich"             "1.2.2012"
3.  "00547"     "1.3.2013"  "65A565"     "44654789621789"       "GR"         "Huston Street"        "London"         "1.3.2012"
4.  "00214"     "1.3.2013"  "789789"     "28736428742313"       "USA"        "Next Street"      "Munchester"         "1.4.2013" 
5.  "00547"     "1.4.2013"  "789856"     "74789798564656"       "USA"        "Pro Nano 21"      "Munchester"         "1.5.2013" 
6.  "00654"     "4.4.2013"  "657989"     "78965423413213"       "USA"        "iuadsgdkj"        "Hamburg"             "6.3.2013"

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**SIFRAD**

```
    -----------------------------------------Table SIFRAD-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
 SIFRA_R        IME     OSTALI_POD      DATUM_UNOSA   DATUM_PROMJENE    RADNIK_UNIO DATUM_ISTEKA
    00214       Test123     Head of IT      31.12.2012  1.1.2013    333333123   1.5.2019
    00547       Aladin      Economic        8.5.2012    2.3.2013    32111111    31.12.2012
    00654       TestTest    Head of Management  2.2.2013    4.5.2014    11111111    1.1.2016
    0214        AaBbCc      Business        3.2.2014    6.5.2014    66666666    2.9.2019
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After combining `SIFRA_RAD` (table `KPOL`), `IME` (table `SIFRAD`), `DAT_IZD` (table `KPOL`) it should look like this

```
SIFRA_RAD     IME        DAT_IZD
------------------------------------
"00654"     "TestTest   "1.4.2013"
"00547"     "Aladin "   "1.5.2013"
"00214"     "AaBbCc"    "4.4.2013"
```

It should display all employee how release`(DAT_IZD)` policy in `2013 year`

So far what I did is following query:

```
SELECT P.SIFRA_RAD, S.IME, P.DAT_IZD
FROM AUTO.SIFRAD S
LEFT JOIN AUTO.KPOL P ON S.IME = P.SIFRA_RAD 
                      AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P.DAT_IZD) = 2013;
```

But so far I can't get any data in table.

After I use `SELECT` statment for table `KPOL`  to select `SIFRA_RAD` and `DAT_IZD` by using following query I get:

```
select sifra_rad, dat_izd 
from kpol 
where extract(year from dat_izd) = '2013'  
order by dat_izd asc
```

I believe the problem comes from my query. Can anyone help me guys to find what is the problem here?

Table `KPOL`:

```
SIFRA_RAD   DAT_IZD
----------------------    
00654       1.1.2007
00654       1.1.2007
00221       1.1.2007
00698       2.1.2007
00987       3.3.2013
00214       3.4.2013
00698       3.5.2013
etc     etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you join tables on `SIFRA`, e.g.

```
select p.sifra_rad, s.ime, p.dat_izd
from kpol p join sifrad s on p.sifra_rad = s.sifra_r
where extract (year from p.izd_dat) = 2013
```

Your query joins `IME` and `SIFRA`, which seems to be incorrect.

**[EDIT, with sample data]**

```
SQL> with
  2  kpol (sifra_rad, dat_izd) as
  3    (select '7654' , date '2009-01-01' from dual union all
  4     select '00547', date '2013-03-01' from dual union all
  5     select '00214', date '2013-03-01' from dual union all
  6     select '00547', date '2013-04-01' from dual union all
  7     select '00654', date '2013-04-04' from dual
  8    ),
  9  sifrad (sifra_r, ime) as
 10    (select '00214', 'Test123' from dual union all
 11     select '00547', 'Aladin'  from dual union all
 12     select '00654', 'Test'    from dual union all
 13     select '0214' , 'AbBbCc'  from dual
 14    )
 15  select p.sifra_rad,
 16         s.ime,
 17         p.dat_izd
 18  from kpol p join sifrad s on p.sifra_rad = s.sifra_r
 19  where extract (year from p.dat_izd) = 2013
 20  order by p.sifra_rad;

SIFRA IME     DAT_IZD
----- ------- ----------
00214 Test123 01.03.2013
00547 Aladin  01.04.2013
00547 Aladin  01.03.2013
00654 Test    04.04.2013

SQL>
```

Comment: Depending of SIFRA_R it display which Employee release Policy in 2013

Comment: Why not? It does what you wanted. I edited my answer by providing sample data. Tables are joined on the SIFRA column, for all DAT_IZD rows in year 2013. What do you expect to get out of it, if not what it currently returns?

Comment: I have no idea what it the problem here, maybe in my IDE which is Database Browser running on Windows XP remot machine but this querie doesn return anything to me. I get error
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: I tried it on 11.2.0.4, 12.2.0.1, works OK. On 10.2.0.5 it returns *invalid column aliasing*, but that can be fixed by moving column names into SELECT, e.g. `WITH kpol AS (SELECT '7654' sifra_rad, DATE '2009-01-01' dat_izd FROM DUAL UNION ALL ...` but - other than that, it seems to be OK.